# What are the implications of a low coverage in multiple imputation?

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, multiple-imputation, point-estimation, coverage-probability

When testing multiple imputation algorithms in simulations, the bias of the examined estimates and the 95% coverage rate are often used as a quality metric. I understand that it is generally undesirable to have a low coverage rate. But what if the bias of the estimates is low, and the coverage is also low? What does a low coverage rate imply in that scenario? If I am only interested in getting accurate point estimates, does the low coverage rate have any consequences for me?

Comment: What do you mean by "bias of estimates is low" ? If the coverage ratio falls below the nominal rate, the method is too optimistic, leading to false positives.